# Webform to MVC Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a customer who runs an event ticket sales site.  The site uses several APIs that interface with ticket sales companies.  Users view ticket/seat availability for a specific event in the form of a Google Map that plots seat availaiblity on the venue image for the event.

The site was written using ASP.NET 3.5 and deployed to the customer's server without source code.  Some changes were made by a previous developer by de-compiliing the existing DLL and making subsequent changes.  Thus, the original source code is not usable and not available.

My customer is interested in URL routing as an enhancment and use of "friendly" URLs instead of the long query string for each event.

What are some good benefits of using ASP.NET MVC2 for the redevelopment of the site?  Besides URL Routing, what other improvements can we site in a non-technical way?

Thanks much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/14/asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx

Key Point In My Opinion:
It will enable you to easily maintain separation of concerns in your applications, as well as facilitate clean testing and TDD.